# Password field is automatically filled with asterisks

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
<tr>
    <th class="editAddLabel">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.loginVM.password, "Password:")</th>

    <td class="editAddField">@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.loginVM.password, new { maxlength = "20" })
        <div class="error">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.loginVM.password)
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="editAddLabel">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.loginVM.password, "Confirm Password:")</th>

    <td class="editAddField">@Html.Password("ConfirmPassword", new { maxlength = "20" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is my view right now, and for some reason when I go to my page to register a user, the Confirm Password textbox is filled with a bunch of asterisks. I can't imagine that the asterisks represent a value because nothing has been added to my model yet. Can somebody tell me how to make the field just be empty?

Comment: Is it just the browser auto filling the password?

Comment: Did you get your problem fixed?

Answer (score 4):

This is your browser filling in a saved password for you. If you want to disable that feature, you need to apply `autocomplete="off"` to the input:

```
@Html.Password("ConfirmPassword", new { maxlength = "20", autocomplete = "off })
```

Comment: I applied the change but it still fills the password box with a bunch of asterisks. On IE and Chrome, it is only the "Confirm Password" that has asterisks, while on Firefox, but the "Password" and "Confirm Password" boxes are automatically filled in @DavidG

Comment: That's because his code is doing the same incorrect usage of Html.Password(). The second parameter is not HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

That's because [`Html.Password`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.password(v=vs.118).aspx) sees the second parameter as the field value. So your code `@Html.Password("ConfirmPassword", new { maxlength = "20" })` is passing `'{ maxlength = "20" }'` as the initial value to your field.

This is the HTML markup that your code generates... Notice the value.

```
<input id="ConfirmPassword" 
       name="ConfirmPassword" 
       type="password" 
       value="{ maxlength = 20 }">
```

If you change the HTML in Chrome (using Developer tools), and remove the `type="password"`, you'd see the value in the field in clear text.

I suggest using [`Html.PasswordFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.passwordfor(v=vs.118).aspx) which is what you did for the other password field. It removes the need to specify string for property names.